# Map inside a map in Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I have a code in getting the value of a map named PUJ.

```
Map<String, Object> map = document.getData();
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getKey().equals("PUJ")) {
        Log.i(TAG, entry.getValue().toString());
    }
}
```

Is it possible to get only the values: **ABC123, YAG916**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nested maps are also `Map<String, Object>`, just like the document data. You can cast it if you want to assume the type:

```
Map<String, Object> map = document.getData();
Map<String, Object> puj = (Map<String, Object>) map.get("PUJ");
Set<String> keys = puj.keysSet();
// keys is now a Set that contains both "ABC123" and "YAG916"
```

But you should also check it with `instanceof` to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Map<String, Object> map = document.getData();
    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
        if ("PUJ".equals(key) && map.get(key) instanceof Map) {
            Map<String, Object> pujMap = (Map<String, Object>) map.get(key);
            // 
        }
    }
```